# Convert Text to Title Case Recursively Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change all instance of text in an HTML document to title case. The jQuery code here works for only single occurrence.

How can this be made to work recursively? :

```js
var ele = $('h3'); 
ele.text(toProperCase(ele.text())); 

function toProperCase(str)
{
    var noCaps = ['of','a','the','and','an','am','or','nor','but','is','if','then', 
'else','when','at','from','by','on','off','for','in','out','to','into','with'];
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt, offset){
        if(offset != 0 && noCaps.indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) != -1){
            return txt.toLowerCase();    
        }
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>THE QUICK BROWN FOX IS ABOUT TO JUMP OVER THE FENCE</h3>

<h3 style="color: red;">HELLO THERE</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` only applies to the first element, use a loop

```
var ele = $('h3'); 
ele.each(function() {
    $(this).text(toProperCase($(this).text())); 
}
```

```js
var ele = $('h3'); 
ele.each(function() { 
    $(this).text(toProperCase($(this).text())); 
});

function toProperCase(str)
{
    var noCaps = ['of','a','the','and','an','am','or','nor','but','is','if','then', 
'else','when','at','from','by','on','off','for','in','out','to','into','with'];
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt, offset){
        if(offset != 0 && noCaps.indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) != -1){
            return txt.toLowerCase();    
        }
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>THE QUICK BROWN FOX IS ABOUT TO JUMP OVER THE FENCE</h3>

<h3 style="color: red;">HELLO THERE</h3>
```